# How to provide a demonstration of Wordpress for new customers

Tags: customization

I'm a website builder.

I'd like to show potential customers the admin section of a Wordpress install.

I'm comfortable setting up a separate install in a demo. sub-domain, but I don't know how to go about maintaining a consistent experience for each new visitor.

I'd like to reset the content every hour or so.

Do I do this with a cron job, which dumps database tables, and re-imports them? If so, I don't know how this is done, as I'm not a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting; I have never done this before. I preferred to create ScreenCast videos.

I don't see any better alternative to using Cron Job for automation of database reset. Here is the link I found that may help you:

- [How to reset MySQL Database using Cron Job](http://webinaction.co.uk/coding-tutorials/mysql-cron-jobs/)
- [Automated Reset of MySQL database to fresh install](http://peakmarketingsystems.com/automated-reset-of-a-mysql-database-to-a-fresh-install/)

Here are a few Wordpress-specific links that may prove helpful to you:

- [How to reset Wordpress database to default settings](https://longren.io/how-to-reset-wordpress-database-to-default-settings/)
- [Wordpress Database Reset (Plugin)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-database-reset/)

Comment: Tip: You should add the code to the answer and use the link as reference, not as answer.